# Getting error while commiting in the SQLAlchemy database

Tags: python, flask

I'm working on a small flask [tutorial](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database/page/0#comments) and after add some data, I try to commit inside the database. And, in that time, I get the following error,

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: user [SQL: u'INSERT INTO user (nickname, email) VALUES (?, ?)'] [parameters: ('john', 'john@email.com')]
```

This table stands with the mdoel provided in the `models.py` file:

```
from app import db

class User(db.Model):

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nickname = db.Column(db.String(64), index=True, unique=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(120), index=True, unique=True)
    posts = db.relationship('Post', backref='author', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.nickname)


class Post(db.Model):   

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    body = db.Column(db.String(140))
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'))

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Post %r>' % (self.body)
```

It seems that the `User` table is not exist or created. So, I have run the following script in the shell,

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI

engine = create_engine(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)

from sqlalchemy import MetaData
m = MetaData()
m.reflect(engine)
for table in m.tables.values():
    print(table.name)
    for column in table.c:
        print(column.name)
```

And I get the result as following,

```
migrate_version
repository_id
repository_path
version

post
id
body
timestamp
user_id

user
id
nickname
email
```

Which means that the `user` table is created and exist. What is the issue here and how to solve it ?

I have a second script also produces the same result:

```
from sqlalchemy import inspect
inspector = inspect(engine)

for table_name in inspector.get_table_names():
   for column in inspector.get_columns(table_name):
       print("Column: %s" % column['name'])
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using the same config (`SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI`) with your app?

Comment: How can I be sure on that ?

Comment: When you create your app `app = Flask(__name__)`, which config did you use?

Comment: I made a mistake and its working fine now. I had to add the `app.config.from_object('config')` line in the `__init__.py` file

Comment: Your command line script shows you that you've defined your SQLAlchemy models, not that the tables exist in the database. To create them you'll need to run `db.create_all()` or use a tool like Alembic (usually via Flask-Migrate).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-SQLAlchemy - When are the tables/databases created and destroyed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243291/flask-sqlalchemy-when-are-the-tables-databases-created-and-destroyed)