# What is the proper way to create a table if it doesn't exists. Flask-SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, database, sqlite, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to use my singleton class to load it from database if it doesn't exists. The problem is I didn't find a proper way to do that, but only catching the exceptions.

So, I've searched for some solutions and people always write something like this:

```
db.session.query(DatasetCounter).filter_by(id=1).first()
```

There my app throws an operational error because it can't find a **'user'** table. Here a quote from log:

> sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) no such table: dataset_counter

All the other approaches brought me to the same error. So, maybe there is a better way to deal with this situation than catching the exception?

**UPD:**
The promlem is not about loading existing tables, but about creating new ones.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flask-SQLAlchemy - When are the tables/databases created and destroyed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243291/flask-sqlalchemy-when-are-the-tables-databases-created-and-destroyed)

Answer (score 0):

Really, maybe a duplicate of the question in the comment. I've just realized that I was calling **db.create_all()** after accessing operations. So, database couldn't find a table. Thx for attention.